# AngularJS. How to get values from lists? Not using ng-repeat nor radio-buttons

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to find a solution for the submitting a value to the scope. I use AngularJS 1.2.5 and Twitter Bootstrap 3. I have created the pluker here http://plnkr.co/edit/4WmMGnVGRe9vICWpT6hC?p=preview

While it works in radio-butons configuration and I get the value (price) by clicking on the options…

```
Radio-buttons list. Price selected: {{changecolour}}
<div class="list-group small">
  <input type="radio" ng-click="changecolour" id="colour01" name="changecolour" ng-model="changecolour" value="300" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right">$ 300 / Kg</span>Red</a>
  <input type="radio" ng-click="changecolour" id="colour02" name="changecolour" ng-model="changecolour" value="660" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right">$ 660 / Kg</span>Green</a>
  <input type="radio" ng-click="changecolour" id="colour03" name="changecolour" ng-model="changecolour" value="920" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right">$ 920 / Kg</span>Black</a>
</div>
```

… I do not get the values when I want to use the same principles in the list-group buttons (better-looking and easier to click on on mobile phones):

```
Problematic—no radio-buttons used. Price selected: {{changecolourNoRadio}}
<div class="list-group small">
  <a ng-click="changecolourNoRadio" id="colour01" name="changecolourNoRadio" ng-model="changecolourNoRadio" value="300" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right">$ 300 / Kg</span>Red</a>
  <a ng-click="changecolourNoRadio" id="colour02" name="changecolourNoRadio" ng-model="changecolourNoRadio" value="660" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right">$ 660 / Kg</span>Green</a>
  <a ng-click="changecolourNoRadio" id="colour03" name="changecolourNoRadio" ng-model="changecolourNoRadio" value="920" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge pull-right">$ 920 / Kg</span>Black</a>
</div>
```

My controller.js looks like…

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('colour', function($scope) {

$scope.changecolour = 'changecolour';
$scope.changecolour = 0;

$scope.changecolourNoRadio = 'changecolourNoRadio';
$scope.changecolourNoRadio = 0;

});
```

I have tried to search for solution, Read up on StackOverflow, but everything I could find was about ng-repeat and generated

lists. But I can't use those because of the styling/design options.

Do you know whether is it possible to solve the problem I have encountered? I think it could be an easy one, maybe I have missed something in documentation. I just can't believe nobody tried to solve it before and got stuck with those ugly radio-buttons (or my google-foo is just too weak?).

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Or in any case, is it possible to style the ng-repeat list in such a way, that it looks like my no-radio-buttons example in plunker? I am just searching for the solutions.

Comment: Not sure whats going on with your controller, setting the save vars to different values right away.  You're not doing things the Angular way.  This example works (link below), but it is NOT the answer / correct solution as I only made what you had work the way you were doing it (not the Angular way). http://plnkr.co/edit/EQnK7g4n6fMfeB8uJwqR?p=preview

Comment: @TheSharpieOne: whoa, it works now! Thank you. So all that was needed is to add  = 300 in ng-click="changecolourNoRadio = 300"? And how bad is this not-angular-way of mine, is there any angular-way that would provide the same visual result? I would LOVE to use ng-repeat, but I could not find a way to make it look like that.

Comment: @user3099838 do you want to use `ng-repeat` for 2nd case?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I am not sure how ng-repeat would work with multi-language application I am creating. I use angular-translate by Pascal Precht there—to translate the values written in the list, on the fly. I am not sure whether it will work ng-repeat way. I am planning to do some calculations with the values I obtain (maybe multiple values and multipliers per button) later in controller.js file (to hide them from the visitors). I am just learning how AngularJs works, and maybe doing things the way they are not supposed to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to do would be to utilize the angular-ui integration with bootstrap that is already done: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  It provides many extra binds and creates directives to use bootstrap.

A in lack of angular-ui bootstrap a solution would be here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OzQnwQiCC4vLFPQ8LEpV?p=preview

It use ng-repeat to look over an array of color items to display.  It stores the currently selected item as `selected`.

```
<h3>Problem—no radio-buttons.<br>Price selected: $ {{selected.price || 0}}</h3>
<div class="list-group small">
    <a ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-click="$parent.selected = color" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active:selected==color}"><span class="badge pull-right">$ {{color.price}}</span>{{color.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Here is the contents of the controller:

```
$scope.colors = [{
  name: "Red",
  price: 300
},{
  name: "Green",
  price: 660
},{
  name: "Black",
  price: 920
}];
```

Note: I also removed that bit of jQuery. It is unneeded as we can get the same result using Angular and not even bothering with bind event listeners in javascript.

**UPDATE**
I added the translation to the example as requested by the original poster
http://plnkr.co/edit/xbmweWSn9Rh6m26bsUO7?p=preview

Configure the translation, translating the words.

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    // Simply register translation table as object hash
    $translateProvider.translations({
        'Red': 'Rojo',
        'Green': 'Verde',
        'Black': 'Black in spanish'
    });   
}]);
```

Tell it where to add the translation filter (IN THE HTML)

```
{{color.name | translate}}
```

Comment: that looks nice! I will try to implement it now and let you know how it works with angular-translate. I am now using vanilla Bootstrap 3. So you are suggesting to hop over to Bootstrap UI, that it would be better in long run?

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap UI will work better with AngularJS in the long run.  Especially if you plan on using a lot of the bootstrap functionality and when you need to easily and effortlessly manipulate what is displayed in bootstrap.

Comment: It does not recognise {{'COLOUR01'|translate}} when I put it instead of Red. As in 
$scope.colors = [{
  name: "{{'COLOUR01'|translate}}",
  price: 300
}

It outputs {{'COLOUR01'|translate}} in the table. :( Other than that it works, but I can't use it for translating. Nonetheless, your answer solves the initial problem I have outlined and I am truly thankful.

Comment: @user3099838 I added an updated example and some explanation, you can see a basic example of how to add the translations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now using Pascal Precht's module, and I have it set up as following: var app = angular.module('colours', ['ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
// add translation tables
$translateProvider.translations('en', translationsEN);
$translateProvider.translations('cz', translationsCZ);
$translateProvider.translations('ru', translationsRU);
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('cz');
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
}]);
var translationsCZ= { etc...

Comment: and it is residing in my main.js file. The controller is in controller.js file. Now I will have to figure out how exactly to interconnect them with the ng-controller data. Btw, the link to the module I use for multiple translations: http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/

Comment: It took me two days to understand and to get together your translation suggestion. A lot of dead ends, experimentations etc (I am new at this, so I am doing it failure-changesomething-repeat-failure-changesomething). Now I get how this works, so I thank you again, esteemed sir, TheSharpieOne.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the solution using list-group buttons, that `<a>` element can't use ng-model directive with the `value` attributes. You have to change the model variables with a function.

Comment: Oh, I see. That somewhat clarifies the fog of my misunderstanding.